# Laravel Job error Job is incomplete class

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I'm getting an error I don't know how to fix so I wondering if I could get some help.

My function:

```
                dispatch(new \App\Jobs\createSqlJob($databaseName, $data['company_name']));
```

This is the error:

```
| 2022-12-13 21:36:38 | Exception: Job is incomplete class: {"__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name":"App\\Jobs\\createSqlJob","99992","99992"} in /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php:116
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(69): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware()
#1 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(98): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call()
#2 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(428): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#3 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(378): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process()
#4 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(172): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob()
#5 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(130): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon()
#6 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(114): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker()
#7 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#8 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#9 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#10 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#11 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call()
#12 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\Container\Container->call()
#13 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(308): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute()
#14 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#15 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1002): Illuminate\Console\Command->run()
#16 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(299): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#17 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#18 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(102): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#19 /var/www/NTTJob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Console\Application->run()
#20 /var/www/NTTJob/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#21 {main} |
```

This error occurs when I run dispatch to a job on server.

Where have I gone wrong?

i tried restart supervisor, but it failed

Comment: Try to check your DB NAME

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the cause, because i have 2 projects in same sever and use same supervisod. and both projects use the queue name as "default", resulting in project 1 running project 2's queue and project 2 running project 1's queue.
My workaround was to reconfigure the file queue.php set queue_name to be different between the 2 projects.
Thanks for everyone's support.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've restarted your queue worker after deployment

Comment: php artisan queue:restart

Answer (score 0):

In your job you are getting (DB NAME:string , COMPANY NAME:string)

> ($databaseName, $data['company_name'])

in error it says you are not giving a proper DB NAME

you are having numbers in it

> ,"99992","99992"

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error randomly and restarting the queue made no difference.  In my case the job was generating a PDF and sending an email.  The job would work sending to one user and not another. The inverse would be happen on the next job.

I refactored my job paying attention to the Laravel documentation about Queued Relationships and model serialization. Model relationships can make serialization of models larger than necessary, specially considering that when your model is deseralized relationships will be re-retrieved. There is not many reasons why you need to maintain relationship data when constructing your job.

[Laravel 10 Queued Relationship Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#handling-relationships)

Adding `withoutRelations()` to my job appears to resolve the issue for me.

```
public function __construct(Deal $deal, User $user)
{
    $this->deal = $deal->withoutRelations();
    $this->user = $user->withoutRelations();
}
```